# How to experimentally determine the chemical potential of salt water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

I have NaCl dissolved in water. How do I find the chem potential?

Comment: It depends of the amount of oxygen gas dissolved in the water.

Comment: @Maurice what do u mean? how do i measure this?

Comment: @Maurice i thought i could get chemical potential by dividing enthalpy by number of moles

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking of the redox potential, when I spoke of dissolved oxygen.

Comment: The chemical potential in what regard? Freezing point of solution, vapor pressure of water, conductivity, redox potential of $\ce{Cl-}$. and so on. Are you considering oxygen and carbon dioxide in the water? "Chemical potential" needs some context.

Comment: @MaxW sorry, i refer to freezing point of solution. the chemical potential of salt water.

Answer (score 2):

A simple aqueous salt solution contains water and salt. One does not generally discuss the "chemical potential of a solution" but rather that of the individual components. Chemical potential is defined by the following equation

$$\mu _i = \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial n_i}\right)_{p,T}$$

where G is the Gibbs free energy and $n_i$ is the amount of substance i in the system (the solution).

One may want to discuss the Gibbs free energy of the solution, which can be related to the composition and chemical potential of individual components as follows:

$$G = \sum_i \mu_i n_i $$

The chemical potential requires a reference scale, so is usually reported as a difference relative to that of pure water, and in lieu of potential one can report the activity since there is a simple relation between the two ($\mu_i \propto RT\ln(a_i)$).

Water activity can be derived from the partial pressure of water vapor in equilibrium with a sample. The activity is equal to the ratio of the partial pressure for the sample to the partial pressure of pure water at the same temperature. There are a variety of methods that can be employed to determine the partial pressure of water, see for instance the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_activity#Measurement).

Comment: i wanna find the chemical potential of salt water

Comment: @RazeXIX I congratulate you on this ambitious goal, but it might help to understand a little better exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Measuring the chemical potential is not exactly like counting beans.

Comment: what other information do i provide oof

Comment: @RazeXIX What are you going to do with the "chemical potential" values? If you can explain this it would go some way to explaining what it is you actually want to know. My guess is you are looking for either the chemical potential of the **water** in a salt solution, OR the chemical potential of the **ions**.

Comment: I am looking at freezing point depression, dissolving salt should reduce the chemical potential of the solution

Comment: @RazeXIX When you look at colligative properties such as freezing point depression it is the chemical potential of the **solvent** that is of interest (or rather, for an ideal solution it is what you measure). So if you are measuring freezing point depression in water, then you would be interested in the chemical potential of water.